# C# Convert to Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays

How can i convert this VBNet code into C#? (`ByteToImage` is a *User Defined Function* use to convert Byte Array into Bitmap.

```
Dim Bytes() As Byte = CType(SQLreader("ImageList"), Byte())
picStudent.Image = jwImage.ByteToImage(Bytes)
```

I tried

```
byte[] Bytes = Convert.ToByte(SQLreader("ImageList")); // Error Here
picStudent.Image = jwImage.ByteToImage(Bytes);
```

but it generates an error saying: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'byte[]'`

What i am doing is basically converting an Image from database to byte array and displaying it on the picturebox.

Comment: I'm assuming that SQLreader is a DataReader?  What type is the column "ImageList?"

Comment: `Convert.ToByte()` returns a single `byte`. You need a method that coverts whatever type `SQLreader("ImageList")` is to a `byte[]`.

Comment: @AJ. ImageList is MediumBLOB.

Comment: It might be worth posting the code for the SQLreader method in your question

Comment: MediumBLOB s a MySQL type, not a .NET type. I bet SQLReader returns a byte array wrapped as an object, otherwise your VB code would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have an array of bytes (`byte[]` in C# and `Byte()` in VB.Net) but the `Convert.ToByte` call just returns a simple `byte`.  To make this work you need to cast the return of `SQLreader` to `byte[]`.

There is no perfect analogous construct for `CType` in C# but a simple cast here should do the trick

```
byte[] Bytes = (byte[])SQLreader("ImageList");
```

Answer (score 11):

```
byte[] Bytes = (byte[]) SQLreader("ImageList"); 
picStudent.Image = jwImage.ByteToImage(Bytes);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
byte[] Bytes = (byte[])SQLreader("ImageList");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

CType is the equivalent of a type cast, not an actual conversion.Besides,  Convert.ToByte tries to convert its input to a single byte, not an array. The equivalent code is

```
byte[] bytes=(byte[])SQLreader("ImageList");
```